# Unable to import database mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am getting below error while tried to import database.:

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> ```
> Unexpected character. (near "$" at position 124)
> Unexpected character. (near "$" at position 127)
> Unexpected character. (near "$" at position 130)
> ```
>
> SQL query:
>
> INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `email`,
>   `session`, `ip`, `last_login`) VALUES (1, Admin, admin,
>   $2y$10$wO2UnL9grzC2HrzFFL8CLOluwPzknWT.MdzmJuAOKAjwhPDaqug4e,
>   mlm@hotmail.com, c85a1e99b56a9f331d473b72d2595ab7, 49.35.8.231,
>   1511538295)
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '@hotmail.com, c85a1e99b56a9f331d473b72d2595ab7, 49.35.8.231,
>   1511538295)' at line 1

not getting what causing this error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape and quote any literal strings when coming from any programming language.  If it is coming from somewhere else, elaborate on how the "import" is being performed.